# C# - Como colocar um endereço secundario no WebBrowser

Tags: url, visual-studio-2015, navegador-de-internet

Olá,
Como colocar endereço secundário no WebBrowser no Visual Studio 2015.

```
        // webBrowser1
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.webBrowser1, "webBrowser1");
        this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
        this.webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://google.com.br", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Caso esse endereço esteja indisponível ele ira procurar um secundário, para que não retorne um erro do browser. (Que convenhamos é muito feio)

Ou simplesmente fazer uma verificação para ver se essa pagina está disponível. Caso contrario retorne um erro pelo MessageBox.

Comment: Ou simplesmente fazer uma verificação para ver se essa pagina está disponível. Caso contrario retorne um erro.